# File::Find in Perl - Looking for files only

Tags: perl

I have a script like this to list every FILES inside my root path

```
use strict;
use File::Find qw(find);
my $path = "<my root path>";

find(\&Search, $path);

sub Search{
    my $filename = $File::Find::name;
    if(-f $filename){
        print $filename."\n";
    }   
}
```

My point is to try to list all the FILES. However, it also listed the symlink inside my $root. I modify my Search function like this and it worked:

```
sub Search{
    my $filename = $File::Find::name;
    #Check if $filename is not symlink first
    if(!-l $filename){
        if(-f $filename){
            print $filename."\n";
        }  
    }   
}
```

But it seem awkward right ? Why do we need two if condition just to verify $filename is the real file and not a symlink !!!

Is there anyone can suggest a better, more decent solution for this ?

Thank you and best regards.

Alex

Comment: I think that `(! l $filename)` should be `(! -l $filename)`.

Comment: Related: [Should -f test return true for symlinks?](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1059303) on PerlMonks

Answer (score 2):

`-f` is testing for file, and that *includes* symlinks. So yes, you do have to test both.

One slightly useful thing, is that you can probably just do:

```
if ( -f and not -l ) {
```

because `File::Find` sets `$_` to the current file, and the [file test](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html)s default to using that too. (won't work if you turn on `no_chdir` though).

You may also want to consider [`File::Find::Rule`](http://search.cpan.org/~rclamp/File-Find-Rule-0.34/lib/File/Find/Rule.pm) as an alternative to `File::Find`.

Comment: `-f and not -l _` might be faster to prevent another `stat` call.

Answer (score 2):

[`stat`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html) and [`lstat`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/lstat.html) are identical except when it comes to symlinks. The former collects information about the linked file, whereas the latter collects information about the link itself.

The `-X EXPR` uses `stat`. `lstat` is needed here.

```
sub Search {
    my $filename = $File::Find::name;

    if (!lstat($filename)) {
        warn("Can't stat $filename: $!\n");
        return;
    }

    say $filename if -f _;
}
```

Bonus: Error checking becomes much simpler when you pre-call `stat` or `lstat`.